# Why show blur xml views in Preview tab on Android studio 3.3

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-studio-3.3

I updated Android Studio to 3.3, and after this update, it shows me blurred XML views and layouts in the preview tab.

See below:

[image: Blurry XML preview in preview tab]

How can I fix this problem on Android studio 3.3?

Answer (score 0):

There is an open ticket for this issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/110463869

You can try bellow instructions and see if it solves your issue:

> Go to 'Help' tab and click on 'Edit Custom Properties'. It might ask
>   you to generate a file if it doesn't already exist. Once this
>   properties file was made, I wrote 'hidpi=false' (no quotations) on a
>   new line, saved it, and restarted Android Studio.

Comment: I used your help. but set small all of my android studio views !!! how can i fix it?

Comment: What do you mean by "set small all views" ? If this doesn't work you can easily revert by deleting the property and going to File -> Invalidate Cache/Restart